# Has a carbon analogue of poly(dimethylsiloxane) been synthesized?

Tags: polymers

Consider [poly(dimethylsiloxane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane) (PDMS), a member of the family of silicone polymers:

[image: PDMS]

Now, imagine its carbon analogue:

[image: 'PDMC']

I've not been able to find any evidence that this carbon analogue has been experimentally prepared. Searching for "poly(dimethylalkoxane)" got me nowhere.  I eventually searched for "dimethyl polyoxymethylene," which turned up the unsubstituted variant of the above, [polyoxymethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyoxymethylene) (POM):

[image: polyoxymethylene]

as well as methyl-capped POM oligomers, [polyoxymethylene dimethyl ethers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyoxymethylene_dimethyl_ethers):

[image: dimethyl POM ether]

But, no "poly(dimethyloxymethylene)" was forthcoming.

**Has the carbon analogue of poly(dimethylsiloxane) been synthesized? If so, what name has it been given?**

Comment: What you are looking for is the polymer of acetone, not "poly(dimethylalkoxane)".

Comment: @DHMO Sure! Whatever it would be called, I haven't found the name yet. If you find it and post an answer with a link & description... winner!

Comment: I have not been able to find anything... acetone does have dimers and trimers but those are not what you would expect...

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0032386170900807 http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/apmc.1996.052360101/pdf

Comment: So, if I read those links correctly, @Mithoron, the acetone polymerization apparently goes to products other than the polymer of interest?

Comment: Yeah, condensation seems prevalent.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25115/acetone-and-sodium-hydroxide/

Comment: So, @CurtF., this is just supporting the argument that polymerization of acetone does not yield the polymer of interest?

Comment: Yes, that's right Brian.

Comment: The dimer exists, at least in [chemical databases](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/19028580#section=2D-Structure), and it is called _2,2'-oxydipropan-2-ol_.  However, according to ChemDoodle the proper IUPAC name is _2-(1-hydroxy-1-methylethoxy)-2-propanol_.  I didn't find any evidence for the existence of the trimer or polymer in any databases, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments to the original question do well to demonstrate that acetone polyacetal (or polyacetone; names in the literature vary, but these are the most common) is extremely difficult to produce by typical polymerization methods; this is mainly due to thermodynamic reasons, though acetal dimers and trimers of acetone have been produced at very low temperatures.<sup>1</sup>

Polyoxymethylene is the polymeric form of paraformaldehyde (formaldehyde oligomers), which forms spontaneously in aqueous solutions of formaldehyde. The methyl-capped paraformaldehyde and polyoxymethylene would form if methanol is added to the solution; indeed, this is actually typically done to limit the length of paraformaldehyde oligomers. Polyoxymethylene, as a homopolymer, is quite stable and machinable, provided end-capping is performed; this is typically done with acetic anhydride.<sup>2</sup>

---

1. Burnop, V. C. E. *Polymer* **1965,** *6* (8), 411-417. DOI: [10.1016/0032-3861(65)90025-X](https://doi.org/10.1016/0032-3861(65)90025-X)
2. Boyer, Lyndon D.; Sorenson, Wayne R.. Polyoxymethylene process. U.S. Patent 3355428, issued November 28, 1967.